# Why doesn't assigning a new value to a controls location property change its location at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

Whenever I need to move a control's location on a form at run-time, I have to assign new values to its Top and Left Properties. Why doesn't the Location property do the trick?

For example I should be able to do:

```
private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Location = e.Location;
            }
          
        }
```

but that doesn't work and instead I have to do it this way:

```
private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Left = e.X + ((Button)sender).Left;
                ((Button)sender).Top = e.Y + ((Button)sender).Top;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two code snippets are not equivalent.

The `MouseEventArgs` reports coordinates *relative to* the control you've attached the `MouseMove` event to, in this case the Button.

In the first example, `e.Location` is `0,0` when the mouse is located at the top-left corner of the Button. The Button's location is then set to `0,0`, but since *its* location is relative to the Form it's on, your button jumps to the top-left corner of the Form.

In the second example, you're setting the location correctly by adding `e.X` and `e.Y` to the existing `Left` and `Top` properties of the Button, respectively.

---

To "fix" the first example, you'd have to modify it to take into account the current position of the Button:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    var b = ((Button) sender);
    b.Location = new Point(b.Left + e.X, b.Top + e.Y);
}
```